# Routing in MVC not finding the new url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I Am not understanding this concept, so after doing a manual and read a few articles I decide to ask you all.

I want to change, just for testing, from:

> localhost/Home/List

To:

> localhost/Custom/List

So my:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute("Custom", "Custom/List/",
        new
        {
            Controller = "Home",
            Action = "List"
        });

}
```

But is is not working. The first url still working but the second one is not finding anything.

Thanks

Comment: Is that the only route definition in your `RouteConfig.cs` file?

Comment: @StephenMuecke. In Global.asax

Comment: I modified RouteConfig.cs and I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: You routes are in the wrong order (the first match wins). Swap them and `..../Custom/List` will work fine

Comment: That is. Thanks @StephenMuecke :)

Comment: I did not know that we can put Routes in GLobal.Asax file too. I thought it can only reside in RouteConfig.cs. :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes are matched in order and your `Default` route matches any url with between zero to 3 segments, so `../Custom/List` calls the `List()` method of `CustomController`.

You need to change the order of your routes so that the `Custom` is before the `DefaultRoute`.  `../Custom/List` will then match that route first and go to the `List()` method of `HomeController`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand the mechanism now.